# Can you put a kickstand on the righthand side?

Tags: rack, panniers, kickstand

Kickstands are always on the left, likely because gears occupy the righthand side.  Has anyone had success with installing a kickstand on the right side?

After using my left-side pannier routinely for six years, I've noticed that my left leg might be a bit stronger (or at the very least, provides better balance in yoga).  To switch it up, I now load up the right pannier.  But without the kickstand to provide counter-balance, my bike inevitably topples over at every stop.

I ride a 1970s Schwinn Le Tour with a hefty touring rack.

Comment: The standard kickstand mounts just behind the bottom bracket.  The chainring(s) on the right side would interfere with its deployment.

Comment: The easy solution would be to switch the pannier to the other side when using the kickstand.

Comment: You're always going to have one leg stronger than the other. I'm also sceptical about how much effect changing the panniers around will have.

Answer (score 10):

You should look into getting a [folding double kickstand.](https://www.google.com/search?q=folding+double+kick+stand) They're great for loaded bikes. Both legs fold off to the left side, but when you kick it down one leg supports each side so the bike stays perfectly upright.

Comment: Pletscher, Greenfield, Velo Orange...all make very nice models. They're great!

Comment: The other option here being a full double kickstand, either at the kickstand plate, or at the rear axle at the drop-out.